# Generically obtain a Scala type's manifest

Tags: scala, manifest

Is there a way to generically obtain a Scala type's manifest? For example, if I only have a Class reference to work with, is there a way I can obtain its corresponding manifest?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scala's built-in `implicitly[T]` will get you an implicit value of type T (if one exists).  So `implicitly[Manifest[T]]` will return a Manifest for type T.

If you have a Class reference, you can get the Manifest for the Class like this:

```
def manifestFor[T: Manifest](c: Class[T]) = implicitly[Manifest[T]]

class Foo
val x =  new Foo
manifestFor(x.getClass)
//scala.reflect.Manifest[_ <: Foo] = _ <: Foo
```

The Manifest's type is `_ <: Foo` instead of just `Foo`, but they are equal.

```
implicitly[Manifest[Foo]] == manifestFor(x.getClass)
//Boolean = true
```

Comment: You can also use `manifest[T]` which makes generally the same as `implicitly[Manifest[T]]`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was trying to do something similar, but reflectively. I had no class symbol at compile time available. I had to use this code, not so obvious from the scaladocs, whith multiple non-obvious and misleading methods present near that point, so that it would likely be useful to others out there.

```
Manifest.classType(Class.forName(className))
```